# Unexpected error merging three point shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, error-999998

I get the following error when I try to merge the files:

[image: Merge error]

The error says that there is an unexpected error. I have deleted the lock files and an empty ArcMap document. It still gives me this error.

Comment: Please post your error messages as TEXT not as an image.  To get the text, copy any past the top-level "Messsages" item from your screenshot there.

Comment: Was the merge run with background processing enabled?  Some people have reported this error was fixed by disabling background processing (I know... doesn't make sense).

Comment: We always got this error on appends (never do merges) until we disabled background processing. BP creates locks that get in the way of updating files (odd but true).